# URL was not found on this server - nginx django

Tags: python, django, nginx

I'm having trouble getting a new Django app to render when I go to the url. I just get a 'Not Found The requested URL /spacegame/ was not found on this server.' error. I 'installed' the app in settings.py,setup the url patterns in mains urls.py and app urls.py, and created the app views.py. It is working on my Django development server, but not on production server. I think it could also be the nginx settings, but not sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The app name is 'spacegame'.

main urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', include('homepageapp.urls')),
    url(r'^spacegame/', include('spacegame.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls)
]
```

spacegame.urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^spacegame/$', views.index, name='index')
]
```

spacegame.views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the spacegame index.")
```

nginx conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ::removed:: ;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

    root /home/projects/aar/aarcom;

    location = /favicon.ico {
        access_log off; log_not_found off;
        }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/projects/aar/aarcom/aarcom.sock;
    }

    location /static {
        allow all;
        alias /home/projects/aar/aarcom/static;
        }

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
        }
}
```

Comment: Your current configuration should expose index view under `/spacegame/spacegame/` URL, the first part is defined in your main urls and the second in your spacegame urls. Could you check what happens, if you go to that URL?

Comment: Thank you for your response @mateuszb. I went to /spacegame/spacegame/ and I still got a Not Found error. I've been reading up on location directives in nginx to see if I maybe have that piece wrong. The fact that it is working on my development server makes me think it's something with the server, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Figured it out! I had to restart gunicorn after changes were made. Sometimes it's the simplest things.